# Javascript based npm module import type declaration warning message in vscode

Tags: npm

I imported the javascript npm module that I developed myself in the vscode react project.
However, I get a warning message like this.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '(module name)'. '(module path)/(module name)/dist/(module name).js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/(module name)` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '(module name)';`
```

I don't understand why the warning message pops up even though the react project is not a typescript template.
Is it because vscode basically performs type checking?
If I don't want the warning message to appear, is there something I'm doing wrong?

I figured out how to clear the warning message in vscode settings itself, how to redeploy after including the .d.ts file, etc., but I couldn't find a fundamental solution to get rid of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the issue of getting unnecessary `typescript` warnings and errors in `.js` files. I researched about it and found out that there is a built-in extension in vs code `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` that is responsible for this unnecessary warning.

You can solve it by disabling the built-in extension. In Extension, type `@builtin` and find out the `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` and disable it for the workspace in which you don't want it. It should fully get rid of the type checking for this workspace. If you want more control over your type validation, you can use eslint.
I hope it will help to solve your issue.

[image: JS File With TS Error:]

[image: After Disabling the extension:]

**Other extensions also can cause this issue, so if it doesn't solve your issue you can share your active extension list and setting to help everyone get a better grasp of your situation.